# Is there a way to know whether a user has typed the password manually or auto logged in from the saved passwords?

Tags: javascript, web, backend, web-development-server

Example: I want to implement a way such that after every 3rd auto-login (logging in from saved passwords) the user must type the password manually, which means that he/she cannot auto-login 4 consecutive times from the saved passwords.

Irrespective of the technologies to be used, I would like to know if such thing  is possible....

Comment: What's the context? At first glance this seems like a terrible idea because you are essentially preventing people to use long generated passwords via password managers.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yes, I understand but I just wanna know if such a thing can be done. If YES, then please let me know HOW?